# How to execute python script with arguments from the "frozen" Python binary?

Tags: python

I have built a python binary with embedded frozen modules and some main script. Let's call the binary `pyemb`.

I want to use some of frozen modules from other python scripts - it seems that the best solution is to provide interface from `pyemb`, like:

```
pyemb python "somescript.py --arg1 --arg2 arg3"
```

But how can I implement the command `python` within my python script itself?

There are `exec` and `execfile` Python functions, but they don't work with arguments and other command-line stuff.

Comment: How should it be different from `pyemb "somescript.py --arg1 --arg2 arg3"`?

Comment: @pacholik it's a simple interface sugar - `pyemb` is intended to do some useful things other than running python scripts, so the `python` is just an interface command.

Comment: So *pyemb* is not Python interpreter? Is it supposed to run *real Python* when you type `pyemb python`?

Comment: @pacholik It's supposed to emulate or simulate or partially implement real Python behavior - especially the part about running scripts with arguments, as the question states.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't get it. And what do you mean when you say *within my python script itself*? What python script?

Comment: @pacholik I mean that I want execute custom python-script with args using only python language - without external Python, without shell or something else. The main goal is to preserve frozen modules, so that custom script can import them.

Comment: And how should we know that when we know nothing about this *pyemb*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112401/discussion-between-abyss-7-and-pacholik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this should work:

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'python':
    sys.argv.pop(1)
    import runpy
    runpy.run_path(sys.argv[1], run_name="__main__")
```

The module [runpy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html) comes very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `sys.argv` to parse your command line arguments.

```
import sys
import subprocess

print sys.argv
if sys.argv[1] == 'python':
    subprocess.Popen([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]])
elif sys.argv[1] == 'notepad':
    subprocess.Popen([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]])
```

Result:

```
>> python scratch.py python argument
['scratch.py', 'python', 'argument']
python: can't open file 'argument': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

>> python scratch.py python "argument argument2"
['scratch.py', 'python', 'argument agument2']
python: can't open file 'argument agument2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

For more powerful argument parsing, I'd suggest `argparse`.